# line by line date dropdown select menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a select dropdown box for my wordpress site. When i click, it will have 7 options of dates starting from the next day to 7 days from now.

I have this code done, to get the current date and the days ahead.

```
<?phpforeach( range(0,6) as $cnt ){
echo strtoupper( date('D d M Y',strtotime( "today + $cnt day") ) ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

or

```
$days = new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 7, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
foreach ($days as $day) {
echo strtoupper($day->format('D d M Y')) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

How do i create a select menu. Where when i click it, The options are as such:

Monday, 26 October 2015

Tuesday, 27 October 2015

and so on.

I tried for hours :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the dates as an option for your select box. For that you can use something like this:

```
<select name="select-box-name" id="give-an-id-of-your-choice">
    <option value="">Select a date</option> <!-- this will be the default selected option if nothing is set -->
    <?php foreach( range(0,6) as $cnt ){
        echo "<option value='".strtoupper( date('D d M Y',strtotime( "today + $cnt day") ) )."'>".strtoupper( date('D d M Y',strtotime( "today + $cnt day") ) )."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

If your really want to have two different format of dates, ie timestamp as input and Monday 21 Oct 15 as displayed, you can change the code as follows:

```
<select name="select-box-name" id="give-an-id-of-your-choice">
<option value="">Select a date</option> <!-- this will be the default selected option if nothing is set -->
<?php foreach( range(0,6) as $cnt ){
    $date = strtotime( "today + $cnt day");
    echo "<option value='".$date."'>".format_date_option($date)."</option>";
}
?>
```

```
<?php
function format_date_option($input_date_ts){
    return date("D d M y",$input_date_ts);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that to the functions.php of my site but it get's an error. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: i am getting an error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/dilmarc2/public_html/philmart/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper-child/functions.php on line 13 "

Comment: my complete functions.php file is as such: